# Java 8 Completable Future - parallel execution

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

I'm testing how `CompletableFuture` works. I am interested in how to execute tasks in parallel:

```
try {
          CompletableFuture one = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
          throw new RuntimeException("error");
          });
          CompletableFuture two = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("2"));
          CompletableFuture three = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("3"));
          CompletableFuture all = CompletableFuture.allOf(one, two, three);
          all.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
           System.out.println(e);
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
           System.out.println(e);
}
```

In this case they will be executed all.

**1**. Is it possible to interrupt all running threads when threre is an exception in one of them?

**2**. When this code is inside a class' method which can be invoked from different threads will it be threadsafe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1.Is it possible to interrupt all running threads when there is an exception in one of them?

Yes, it is possible. All threads should have an access to common object which state can be changed and read by other threads. It can be for example `AtomicInteger`. See below example:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Dates {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            AtomicInteger excCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
            CompletableFuture one = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new ExcRunnable(excCounter));
            CompletableFuture two = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new PrintRunnable("2", excCounter));
            CompletableFuture three = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new PrintRunnable("3", excCounter));
            CompletableFuture all = CompletableFuture.allOf(one, two, three);
            all.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class ExcRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final AtomicInteger excCounter;

    public ExcRunnable(AtomicInteger excCounter) {
        this.excCounter = excCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int millis = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 5000);
        System.out.println("Wait " + millis);
        Threads.sleep(450);

        // Inform another threads that exc occurred
        excCounter.incrementAndGet();

        throw new RuntimeException("error");
    }
}

class PrintRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final String name;
    private final AtomicInteger excCounter;

    public PrintRunnable(String name, AtomicInteger excCounter) {
        this.name = name;
        this.excCounter = excCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int counter = 10;
        while (counter-- > 0 && excCounter.get() == 0) {
            System.out.println(name);
            Threads.sleep(450);
        }
    }
}

class Threads {
    static void sleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

We have 3 tasks: two which prints it's name and one which throws exception after some time. Before exception is thrown counter is incremented to inform other tasks that one of them failed and they should finish executions. Print jobs are checking this counter and in case condition is not met they finish it's job. When you comment `excCounter.incrementAndGet();` line other tasks finish theirs job without knowing that one of them thrown exception.

> 2. When this code is inside a class' method which can be invoked from different threads will it be thread safe?

Take a look on the definition of [thread safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). For example, assume that print tasks increment common counter with every printed line. If counter is primitive `int` it is not thread safety because counter value could be replaced. But if you use `AtomicInteger` it is thread safety because `AtomicInteger` is thread safety.

Comment: Nice, It will work also with ExecutorService, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## 1

if any of your async task throw exception, all.get() will throw exception.
That means, you can cancel all CF in catch clause.
But, your async tasks need to be interrupt friendly i.e. check for interrupt flag periodic or handle InterruptedException and return early.

> Task cancellation should always be handled using interrupt mechanism

## 2

All the reference variables mentioned by you are local, so there is no need to worry about thread safety. Local variables are always thread safe.